# Resizing images in data preprocessing for training convolution network

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to load data from jpeg files to train a convolution network. The images are large, with 24 million pixels however, so loading and using the full resolution is not practical.

To get the images to a more useful format I am trying to load each image, rescale it and then append it to a list. Once this is done, I can then convert the list into a numpy array and feed into the network for training as usual.

My problem is that my data set is very large and it takes about a second to rescale every image, which means it is not feasible to resize every image the way I have currently implemented this:

```
length_training_DF = 30000
for i in range(length_training_DF):
    im = plt.imread(TRAIN_IM_DIR + trainDF.iloc[i]['image_name'] + '.jpg')
    image = block_reduce(im, block_size=(10, 10, 1), func=np.max)
    trainX.append(image)
```

I have also used the following:

```
length_training_DF = 30000
from keras.preprocessing import image
for i in range(50):
    img = image.load_img(TRAIN_IM_DIR + trainDF.iloc[0]['image_name'] + '.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
    trainX.append(ima)
```

Is there any way to load these images more quickly into a format for training a network? I have thought about using a keras dataset, perhaps by using tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(), but the directory in which the image data is stored is not formatted correctly into folders containing the same targets as is required by this method.

The images are for a binary classification problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way would be to write a preprocessing script that loads the large images, rescales them, applies other operations if needed, and then saves each class to a separate directory, as required by `ImageDataGenerator`.

There are at least three good reasons to do that:

- Typically, you will run your training process dozens of time. You don't want to every time do the rescaling or e.g. auto-white balance.
- `ImageDataGenerator` provides vital methods for augmenting your training data set.
- It's a good generator out of the box. Likely you don't want to load entire data set into memory.

Comment: Ok thanks. Does this mean that there is no way of avoiding the long image loading step, and we just have to implement it so that this operation is carried out as few times as possible?

Comment: You don't load all of them at once, but in batches. When a batch is being processed, next batch(es) can be fetched and cached in memory, so there's little to no penalty, as long as you don't have to do any heavy preprocessing. To avoid that we preprocess the data upfront. One can also consider saving the data into e.g. HDF5 or TFRecord (to directly load the data), but I'd not go this route unless I have a very good reason.